# vertical align: middle - why must the first item be aligned middle?

Tags: html, css

In my HTML I have a div which has three divs as children. I would like to have the second and third child (which are a text and button) aligned in the middle.

```
<div class='border'>    
    <div class='inline-block some-image'> <!-- background image here --> </div>
    <div class='inline-block description'> Some Text</div>
    <div class='inline-block button'> <button></button> </div>
<div>
```

My CSS

```
.border {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.some-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 29%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.description {
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button {
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The three divs are inline-block, so that they stay on the same line. But if the first child (.someImage) is not vertical-align: middle, then the following children are not aligned in the middle.
If I just switch the first one to vertical align middle, then they work fine... can anyone explain this to me? 
Do all children have to be aligned in the middle, or can I have select ones align at the top or bottom?

Example not aligning in the middle: http://plnkr.co/edit/1ieeKiDiGjwlQuOojQ3C?p=preview
Example with aligning in the middle: http://plnkr.co/edit/GIHjclutVGtiIiSR305n?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

the button, image and the description are aligned together, not by their parent. so when you align a image on top the other elements are aligned separability, and they aligned middle. so they worked correctly.

Comment: If you look at the firsts plunker, when the first item is aligned top, the other two don't align at the middle. Maybe I don't understand your answer...

Comment: you should compare the elements together not by their parent. "vertical align" doesn't align the elements with their parent, but  align them with the elements that are inline with the current element.